# How to install pytorch on windows subsystem for linux

Tags: pytorch

my windows10 has subsystem for linux of 14.04. I tried  to install pytorch on the preinstalled python2 but couldn't work.The error is: torch-0.2.0.post1-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform. I tried to install python3.6 then install pytorch with it, but still couldn't work.The error is missing module 'apt_pkg'. Anyone has idea on this?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/23223) it should be working now via anaconda's package manager `conda`.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the `whl` filename, there are two bits to pay attention to. Firstly, the `cp27` and secondly the `x86_64` bit.

- That first one tells you that you need `python 2.7` which is the default for the `WSL`, so that's fine.
- The second one tells you that the `whl` has been compiled for a 32 bit computer. If you have a 64 bit computer, it *will* fail.